# Dotnet Highchart Using JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I have a JSON which I created using following code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LocalHost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI");
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 10 x,dt from test4 order by Id desc", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);

string DATA = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

Now I want to use this json in dotnet highcharts.

I tried the following code using DotNet HighChart Library

```
hcVendas.YAxis.Add(new YAxisItem { title = new Title("My Data") });
hcVendas.DataSource = DATA;  
hcVendas.DataBind();
```

Code on aspx code is

```
<cc1:Linechart Id ="hcVendas" runat="server"></cc1:Linechart>
```

I am not getting anything on the aspx page. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Generally, how your JSON looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a button to display the chart which is placed inside Update Panel?

Then you should place the trigger for that button..